# Time series estimation in R vs. Mathematica

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica, time-series

I'm fitting an IMA(1,1) [or ARIMA(0,1,1)] model to a time series. I tried using the `arima` function in R, and the `EstimatedProcess` function in Mathematica (ver. 10), and I got very different results. Why? Are they making different assumptions, valid in different situations? Does anyone have advice on which one I should use?

Example. First, in R.

```
> series <- c(-1.42377, 0.578605, -0.534659, -3.07486, -2.4468,
 -0.508346, -0.216464, -2.7485, -1.93354, -1.07292,
 -1.48064, -1.13934, -1.24597, 1.419, -1.22549,
 -2.44651, 1.54611, 1.80892, -0.863338, 1.21636)
> arima(series, order=c(0,1,1))

Call:
arima(x = series, order = c(0, 1, 1))

Coefficients:
          ma1
      -0.7807
s.e.   0.1548

sigma^2 estimated as 2.227:  log likelihood = -35.03,  aic = 74.07
```

Now, in Mathematica:

```
series = {-1.42377, 0.578605, -0.534659, -3.07486, -2.4468, 
-0.508346, -0.216464, -2.7485, -1.93354, -1.07292, 
-1.48064, -1.13934, -1.24597, 1.419, -1.22549, 
-2.44651, 1.54611, 1.80892, -0.863338, 1.21636};
EstimatedProcess[series, ARIMAProcess[{}, 1, {ma1}, s2]]
```

which yields:

```
ARIMAProcess[{}, 1, {-0.252596}, 3.30217]
```

As you can see, both the estimated MA1 coefficients (-0.7807 in R, -0.2526 in Mathematica) and variances (2.227, 3.302) are rather different.

Thanks lot for any insight or advice,
Mark

Answer (score 3):

OK, I've figured it out. By default, Mathematica functions `EstimatedProcess` and `FindProcessParameters` use the method of moments. R function `arima`, on the other hand, uses maximum likelihood. So if you tell Mathematica to use maximum likelihood, like so

```
series = {-1.42377, 0.578605, -0.534659, -3.07486, -2.4468, 
-0.508346, -0.216464, -2.7485, -1.93354, -1.07292, 
-1.48064, -1.13934, -1.24597, 1.419, -1.22549, 
-2.44651, 1.54611, 1.80892, -0.863338, 1.21636};
EstimatedProcess[series, ARIMAProcess[{}, 1, {ma1}, s2],
 ProcessEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
```

you get the exact same answer as R:

```
ARIMAProcess[{}, 1, {-0.780677}, 2.22661]
```